# App Engine instance not able to connect to Cloud SQL Postgres instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am out of my wits now. I have a Flask Application running on App Engine as a Dynamic instance. This application is supposed to write to Cloud SQL Postgres database.
But I always get:

```
502 Bad Gateway Error
Unable to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()
```

Database connection works fine when I run it locally because I have added my IP Address under Authorized Access.

I have add the `Cloud SQl Client` role to the `{project-id}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` Principal.

Enabled the following APIs:

- Cloud SQL Admin API
- Compute Engine API
- Cloud Build API
- Cloud Logging    API

App.yaml

```
runtime: python310
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app.main:app
env_variables:
  FB_APP_ID: 'YOUR_APP_ID'
  FB_APP_SECRET: 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'
  CLOUD_SQL_USERNAME: 'postgres'
  CLOUD_SQL_PASSWORD: 'pwd'
  CLOUD_SQL_DATABASE_NAME: 'postgres'
  CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME: 'ip'

instance_class: F2
```

Went through this https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-instance-app-engine-flexible but no luck.

I have not enabled the Private IP yet.

> I am using $200 worth of free credits and do not have billing enabled for me yet.
> Hopefully, this is unrelated to my issue.

Comment: None of the details apply to the error. Show what you configured and the code that generates the error message. Include the stack trace or error details which you will find in Cloud logging.

Comment: Do you use app engine flexible or standard? Do you have a public IP or only a private IP on your Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Its a flexible app engine instance. Yes Cloud SQL instance has a public IP address.

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml file?

Comment: Your app engine is not flexible :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running in App Engine, you'll want to connect to your Cloud SQL instance through the Unix socket for public IP.

If you're trying to connect to private IP, you'll need to use a Serverless VPC Access Connector and connect through whatever your instance's private IP is.

See here for details: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#connect_to

Comment: Thank you. I used the connector_unix class for Public Ip Address and It worked like a charm.